# Orm discriminator-column of the parent table must refer to a value which is of a different table

Tags: jpa, orm

The question is quite confusing so I'll describe in detail as follows.

I have a domain object User (which has its respective User table in database). I have another domain Investor (which has its respective Investor table in database) that extends User. Now a  User can be a Investor if User's userType='I'

```
<entity class="User" >
   <table name="domain.Users" />
   <discriminator-column name="user_type" discriminator-type="STRING"/>
</entity>
```

I need to map the user_type to its respective domain and tables.

```
<entity class="domain.Investor" >
  <table name="domain.Users" />
  <discriminator-value>I</discriminator-value>
</entity>
```

In the above code i cannot change the table name to the database's Investor table because the discriminator value is for User's table. I want the xml code where discriminator's column of Users table is I but it should have its own table Investor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investor should be able to use both the User and its own Investor table in a joined table inheritance structure if that is what you need.  This will work out such that each row in User represents a User entity or User subclass, while each User that is really an Investor will also have a row in the Investor table.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance for a simple example of how to set up inheritance - you are missing the `<inheritance strategy="JOINED"/>` tag in User that specifies the JPA inheritance type to use.